# Search just the apps in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, start-menu, windows-search

Is there a way to search just the applications installed in Windows 8.1?

In Windows 8 I could do this but the 8.1 search is much wider scoped. I can do things like press Win+W to search settings but there doesn't seem to be an option that will effectively search the shortcuts in the start menu hierarchy.

My PC is almost seven years old - it runs fine with Windows 8.1 but finding things in the start screen is frustratingly slow.

I've tried defragmenting and have had a little improvement by turning off the Bing integration.

Comment: What about the search bar on the top right in App screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to search only apps when you hit the Windows key in in Windows 8.1:

1. Right click the Taskbar and go to Properties.
2. Change to the Navigation tab
3. Check the "Show the Apps view automatically when I got to Start" box
4. Uncheck the "Search everywhere..." box right below it.

Now if you hit the Windows Key and start typing, it should only search apps.

Comment: Madness the home screen must be turned off in order to just search the apps.  Great solution though, it's been driving me mad! Thanks